# Ubuntu - Is there a way to associate keyboard shortcuts to bring a window to front?

Tags: ubuntu

I am using exactly 3 programs: 
 - a browser
 - a terminal
 - a code editor

I keep all in fullscreen windows.

What I need is to be able to bring any one of them up with a simple keyboard shortcut, like Ctrl+Alt+B for browser, etc.

Alt-Tab sucks because I have to stop and see where the selector is.

Using 3 workspaces is better but still not ideal - I need to think about where I am and where I need to go. E.g. My browser is on top of my terminal and my code editor is to the right of the terminal. So to move from browser to terminal I use Ctrl+Alt+Down, but to move from code editor to terminal I have to do Ctrl+Alt+Left. Instead I should just do Ctrl+Alt+T for terminal, for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Answering my own question if anybody else needs this: Yes, just open the Keyboard application in Settings and set keyboard shortcuts for switching to Workspace 1, 3 and 4 in my case.

Comment: Well, in Windows 7 and up, this is accomplished by using the Win key and a number.  I dont know if gnome/kde/whatever copied that function

Comment: Concerning the terminal program - try `guake`. It's an in-game-like terminal, that shows or hides by a configurable key combination.

Comment: You might want to post you answer as an answer instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 6):

I don't use Unity so this is tested on Cinnamon but the same trick should work in all desktop environments. You can use a tool like [`xdotool`](https://superuser.com/a/183683/151431) or [`wmctrl`](https://superuser.com/a/183681/151431)  that allows you to script your interactions with the X server.

I prefer `wmctrl`, but you can install both with

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
```

First run `wmctrl -l` to see what the names of your open windows are:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x02200007 -1 oregano Desktop
0x0380007f  1 oregano Ubuntu - Is there a way to associate keyboard shortcuts to bring a window to front? - Super User - Mozilla Firefox
0x01c000a3  1 oregano emacs@oregano
0x03c00006  1 oregano Terminal
```

If you scroll right, you'll see that the second is my `firefox` instance showing this page. So, you now activate each of your three windows by name:

```
$ wmctrl -a terminal 
$ wmctrl -a firefox
$ wmctrl -a emacs
```

You can assign shortcuts to each of these commands using your desktop environment's GUI or via a more generic tool such as [`xbindkeys`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91433/22222).

Comment: This is the easiest to implement, among all that I've searched!!